# Windows shuts down unexpectedly on hibernate

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, shutdown, hibernate

I've just bought a new Dell Inspiron 7501 (i7 10750H, nvidia 1650), and after setting up a dual boot with ubuntu 18, i've noticed that the pc fails to restore the previous state when booted up after the hibernation.
The event viewer contains 2 events saying respectively:

- Windows failed to resume from hibernate with error status 0xC000000D
- The previous system shutdown at 23:19:55 was unexpected.

I've tried multiple suggested fixes like:

- Update windows, device drivers and BIOS firmware
- Disable fast boot
- Disable secure boot
- Disable and re-enable hibernation (with full option)
- Check the integrity of the OS (with sfc /scannow, chkdsk and DISM)
- Check the presence of the hiberfil.sys file
- Uncheck the "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" option of the Intel Management Engine Interface

Nothing seemed to work in any way.

Comment: Check if the booting app is interfering with Hibernation. Otherwise, contact Dell Support.

Comment: @John by booting app you mean the grub? And how can i check it?

Comment: You have to go through the Grub log and see if there is any collision/interference  with Hibernate.

Comment: @John nothing strange there, and that makes sense since the pc seems to shut down unexpectedly when trying to hibernate (and not when booting it back up)

Comment: Contact Dell Support to see if they can assist with Power Settings.  Maybe a change to make in BIOS.

Comment: You might/should check Ubuntu communities - AFAIR it is not recommended to dual-boot Windows/Linux with hibernation at all. F.ex., see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125833/is-it-possible-to-hibernate-both-windows-and-ubuntu-in-a-dual-boot-setup